# From the list of arrays user search a number if it is not found then show only a single msg that is not found not multiple times

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int usman[10]={0,5,6,3,5,1,8,5,4};
    int choice;


cout<<"Please Neter A Value To search : ";
cin>>choice;
cout<<endl;

for( int j=0 ; j<10 ; j++)
{
   if(usman[j]==choice)
   {
       cout<<"usman["<<j<<"] = "<<choice<<endl;


   }



}



getch();

return 0;
}
```

Sir,
      There is no error in this program.In This Program i created an Array of Var. which is Initialized . On Screen it ask the user to search any number in the arrays and tells n which indexes it exist.I want to Add one thing that if the given number by the user is not in the array list it simple show a single Msg. that "Given Number is Not Exist" Only only only one time not Multiple times .I mean in evry Rotation of loop when the choice of user is not in the first array and so on it does not show msg every time.
Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:-

Put this at the start :

```
int check=0;
```

After that, put `check=1;` inside `if` at the end.

And then after `for` loop, put this :

```
if (i == 10 && check != 1)
{
    cout<<"The entered value is not found";
}
```

Hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Add in an extra Boolean variable to check if the number was found. If it's found multiple times, applying `found = true` multiple times is the same as just applying it once.

```
bool found = false;
for( int j=0 ; j<10 ; j++)
{
   if(usman[j]==choice)
   {
       cout<<"usman["<<j<<"] = "<<choice<<endl;
       found = true;
   }
}
if (!found)
{
    cout << "The given number does not exist!" << endl;
}
```